# didReceiveRemoteNotification not working ios9

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I follow these steps for push notifications but un able to receive push on my device.

**Steps**

1. making and adding push app id and provisioning profile in my project
2. enable push notifications in my project
3. making p12 file nd .pem file
4. sending .pem file to php developer
5. use following code in my app delegate.m

The code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    //ios 9
    UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
    UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;

    UIUserNotificationSettings *mySettings =
    [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:mySettings];


    return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings {
    if (notificationSettings.types != UIUserNotificationTypeNone) {
        NSLog(@"didRegisterUser");
        [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)devToken 
{
    NSString *token = [[devToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

    Globals *globlClass = [Globals sharedInstance];
    globlClass.DeviceToken = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",token];

    NSLog(@"\n\n\n\n\n device token===%@\n\n\n\n",globlClass.DeviceToken);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)err {
    NSLog(@"failed to regiser %@", err);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo 
{
    NSLog(@"notification options %@", userInfo);

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Super" message:@"welcome" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

    for (id key in userInfo) {
        NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", key, [userInfo objectForKey:key]);
        UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Your title here!" message:@"this gets covered" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

        UITextField *myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 45.0, 260.0, 25.0)];
        [myTextField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        myTextField.text = [userInfo objectForKey:key];
        [myAlertView addSubview:myTextField];
        [myAlertView show];
    }    

}
```

Comment: follow this step by step http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

Comment: Are you sure the server side code is right? And is didRegisterUserNotificationSettings being called? Did you get the token and send it to your server?

Comment: Pay attention to develop and distribution.

Comment: @Ani Khechoya yes i get the token and send it to server

Comment: Then the problem may be with your .pem file. How do you make it? Is your profile for development?

Comment: Any error you are getting from server side?

Comment: @Ani Khechoya Dear i export certificate from key chain, save as p12 and make .pem file on terminal  save to desktop

Comment: Be sure to export private key, not only a public one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register for remote notifications by call this method `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications]` after registering user notification settings.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    //ios 9
    UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
    UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;

    UIUserNotificationSettings *mySettings =
    [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:mySettings];

   //call this method here
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];

    return YES; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in AppDelegate.m:

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }
    else
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
    }
```

working for me for iOS 9.0 and Xcode 7.2.